# How to click on HTML list with no ID

Tags: javascript, html, css, vba

Any help with my issue would be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to use a VBA Macro to click on a link called "Indices"

Here is the relevant HTML code from the webpage:

```
<nav class="platform-navigation ember-view" id="ember24" style="width: 160px;"><div class="animated-section ember-view" id="ember25"><!----></div>
<div class="platform-navigation_menu " style="width: 160px;">
  <ul class="platform-navigation_tree">
      <li title="Search" class="platform-navigation_menu-item--search platform-navigation_item has-action " role="button" data-automation="openSearchFlyout" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-26="26">
        Search
      </li>
      <div class="platform-navigation_menu-divider"></div>
      <li title="Indices" class="platform-navigation_menu-item--asset-class platform-navigation_item platform-navigation_menu-item--INDICES has-action&#10;        &#10;        &#10;        " role="button" data-automation="openIndicesFlyout" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-73="73">
          Indices
      </li>
```

and here is the relevant part of my VBA code:

```
Set tags = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("li")
For Each tagx In tags
    If tagx.Title = "Indices" Then
        tagx.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

I can navigate to the webpage fine, but the code above will not click the "Indices" button.

Thank you very much

Comment: The code I meant to paste did not copy in fill so here it is:

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName

Comment: Looks like it should click but perhaps you need to attach an htmlevent and dispatch it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be searching for "Indices" instead of "li".

getElementsByTagName() works by being given the string you're searching for, not the element type you're looking in.

Here's the code assuming there will only be one with the title "Indices"

```
Set tag = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("Indices")
tag.click
```

Comment: getElementsByTagName returns a collection so your code will fail as .click is not a collection method. Instead, you need to use the appropriate index on the collection before the click